# How do I properly encode JSON in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to create a JSON object to return to a service in swift, but I can't seem to figure out he proper way of encoding it. This is the current code where I am attempting to create the JSON Object:

```
        let jsonObject = [
        "entries" : [
            { "old" : {
                "preferenceOptions" : [
                { "preferenceCategoryCode" : {
                "code":"01",
                    "desc":"Paperless Settings"
                },
                                        "preferenceSubCategoryCode":{
                                           "code":"01",
                                           "desc":"Paperless Settings"
                                        },
                                        "preferenceOptionDescription":{
                                           "text":"Explanation of benefits (EOB)",
                                           "languageCode":"EN"
                                        }
                }

                ]
                }

            }
        ]
    ]
```

and I am getting the error "Consecutive Statements on a line must be separated by a ';' " starting on the line with "Entries"

Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: You've got square brackets wrapping your jsonObject, but it should be curly braces.

Comment: Seems to be more then just that (I tried and same issue is still present)

Comment: You're mixing up JSON and Swift literal collection syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jsonObject` is trying to use raw JSON syntax (with braces for the dictionaries) rather than Swift syntax (where dictionary literals use square brackets). It should be:

```
let jsonObject = [
    "entries" : [
        [ "old" : [
            "preferenceOptions" : [
                [ "preferenceCategoryCode" : [
                    "code":"01",
                    "desc":"Paperless Settings"
                    ],
                    "preferenceSubCategoryCode":[
                        "code":"01",
                        "desc":"Paperless Settings"
                    ],
                    "preferenceOptionDescription":[
                        "text":"Explanation of benefits (EOB)",
                        "languageCode":"EN"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks Rob - this seemed to do the trick - I was unaware of the difference in terms of the bracketing for Swift Vs JSON